# Интегрированная Среда Разработки для С#

Tags: c#, ide

Скажите мне пожалуйста,какая IDE самая лучшая для C#?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста почитайте [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio лучшая из лучших

Comment: Ну тут сейчас не все однозначно, Rider сейчас тоже неплох

Comment: @B.Vandyshev блокнот тоже в принципе не плох...

Comment: Не стоит сравнивать Rider и блокнот, все таки Rider - это IDE